# Нужна помощь с указателями на указатели

Tags: указатели

Попробую сформулировать условие задачи: данную строку str1: "A  roza upala,  na lapu+ Azora!" разделить на отдельные слова с помощью функций strcspn и strspn, первая считает число элементов строки str1, не входящих в строку str2: " ,.!?+-"(строка разделителей) пока в str1 не появятся элементы из str2. Вторую функцию я использовал для того, чтобы определить, элемент , на котором стоит указатель, разделитель или нет.

```
сhar str1[] = "++A  roza upala, na lapu Azora.! ";
char str2[] = " +-.,!?";
char *word = new char [15]; 
char **ptrArray = new char*[20];
int k, n, j, i = 0;
char *pstr1 = str1 , *pfun;
while(pstr1 < str1 + strlen(str1))
{
    n = strspn(pstr1,str2); 
    if (n!= 0) pstr1++;
    else 
    {
        k = strcspn(pstr1, str2);
        pfun = pstr1 + k;

//заполнение указателя
        j = 0;
        for (char *pout = pstr1; pout < pfun; pout++)
        {
            *(word+j) = *pout;
            j++;
        }
        *(word+j) = ' ';

        //заполнение массива указателей указателями на слова
        ptrArray[i] = word;
        delete[]word; // очистка
        pstr1 = pfun + 1;
        i++; // кол-во указателей(слов) + 1
    }
}
//cases for output
if (i < 7) {
    for (int m = i-1; m >= 0; m--)
        cout << ptrArray[m];
}
else {
    for (int m = 0; m < i; m += 2)
        cout << ptrArray[m];
}

//cleaning all up
for (int ii = 0; ii < i; ii++) delete[] ptrArray[ii];
delete[] ptrArray;
```

необходимо сформировать строку из слов, разделённых пробелами, в обратном порядке, если слов меньше семи , иначе каждое второе слово. И вывести на экран.
В своём решении я использовал динамическое выделение сначала под отдельное слово(строку), а потом под массив строк. Указатель WORD нужен для выделения памяти под каждое новое слово(строку). 
Возможно проблема здесь:

```
        for (char *pout = pstr1; pout < pfun; pout++)
    {
        *(word+j) = *pout;
        j++;
    }
    *(word+j) = ' ';

    //заполнение массива указателей указателями на слова
    ptrArray[i] = word;
```

В конце программы пытаюсь через указатели на указатели на слова(строки) организовать нужный мне вывод.

```
if (i < 7) {
    for (int m = i-1; m >= 0; m--)
        cout << ptrArray[m];
}
else {
    for (int m = 0; m < i; m += 2)
        cout << ptrArray[m];
}
```

Помогите, кто сможет!(буду признателен)

Comment: А в чем проблема?  Что вы не можете сделать?

Comment: Ну не работает программа)) А вы считаете, что всё правильно написано? Меня особенно интересует вывод

Comment: "Не работает программа". Как не работает? Не компилируется, вылетает с ошибкой, в консоль выводятся не те данные, в консоль не выводятся данные, в консоль выводятся поврежденные данные, в консоль выводится мусор?

Comment: Мне вот это не нравится: ptrArray[i] = word; 
delete[]word; // очистка  Я не пойму, зачем вы удаляете word? В первой строке вы скопировали указатель на область памяти, где хранится массив word. И во второй строке вы говорите, что эта область памяти уже не нужна, и можно ее занимать другими данными. Пробовали не удалять word в той строке?

Comment: Ну а как?? Я создаю динамический массив указателей с указателями на каждое слово. Для каждого слова нужен свой указатель ( word , как вы поняли ). Он тоже динамический(ну понятно почему) А зачищаю для того, чтобы потом для нового слова был новый указатель( возможно я неправильно динамику понимаю). {PtrArray[i] = word } -- элементу массива указателей присваиваю указатель на слово(тут всё просто вроде) . На вижле ничего не выдавало, а на codeblocks непонятные символы и компилировалось с прерываниями). Когда убрал delete[]word - на вижле выполнилась с прерываниями

Comment: Указатели - тема,  требующая точного понимания. В таких случаях,  когда я точно не знаю,  где ошибка, я делаю так: 1) разбиваю программу на более мелкие кусочки(в вашем случае по циклам) 2) записываю,  как,  по моему мнению, должны выполняться эти кусочки(какие данные должны получаться). 3)сравниваю с тем, что получилось. Да,  и непонятные символы как раз говорят о том,  что вы обращаетесь к памяти,  где находится мусор.

Comment: Отладчиком пользоваться умеете? Добавьте все переменные, которые вас интересуют, в окно watches,  и наблюдайте,  как они изменяются при каждом шаге. Заметите, 
что что-то не так,  как предполагалось - ищите ошибку.

Comment: Нашёл ошибку)) Необходимо было каждое слово(строку) в конце закрывать символом '\0' и убрать delete[]word и ещё я неправильно обращался к элементам word. Нужно было не *(word +j) , а word[j] просто , как в статическом массиве

Comment: Что ж,  теперь ты знаешь,  как искать ошибки. Сейчас сделаю ответ,  а ты поставь плюсик и галочку ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Указатели - тема, требующая точного понимания. В таких случаях, когда я точно не знаю, где ошибка, я делаю так: 
1) разбиваю программу на более мелкие кусочки(в вашем случае по циклам)
 2) записываю, как, по моему мнению, должны выполняться эти кусочки(какие данные должны получаться). 
3)сравниваю с тем, что получилось.

Да, и непонятные символы как раз говорят о том, что вы обращаетесь к памяти, где находится мусор.
Отладчиком пользоваться умеете? Добавьте все переменные, которые вас интересуют, в окно watches, и наблюдайте, как они изменяются при каждом шаге. Заметите, что что-то не так, как предполагалось - ищите ошибку.